How can I copy part of a word file to another word file using Python
"My goal is to write a Python script that copies content between specific flags, such as {{START}} and {{END}}, from one Word file and pastes it into another Word file at a designated location. It's crucial that all content retains its original formatting, so tables remain as tables and text keeps its formatting intact. I've attempted this using the Python zipfile library. My approach involved parsing the 'word/document.xml' file of the source Word file and then inserting the necessary content into the XML of the target Word file. Does anyone have ideas or suggestions on how to achieve this effectively?

import zipfile from lxml 
import etree from bs4 
import BeautifulSoup 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

doc_xml = zip_file.read('word/document.xml')
soup_xml = BeautifulSoup(doc_xml, 'xml')
pretty_xml = soup_xml.prettify()
string_data = doc_xml.decode('utf-8')
print(doc_xml)


doc_xml.writestr('word/document.xml', modified_document_xml)

That is some parts of the code that I Used.

There is a Python library that may be useful for this job. See python-docx.
